# Find the Laurent series of the complex function $\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent series of the complex function $\frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}$ around $z=0$ ?

My goal is to find the residue of this function at $z=0$, in order to calculate the integral : $$\int_{|z-1|=\pi} \frac z{1-\cos z}$$

because $z=0$ is the only singular point at the integral domain. (at least that's what I figured)

I tried to say that when we get close to $z=0$, we can say that $|\cos(z)|\le 1$, so we can expand $\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ into power series and from there to find the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ but couldn't get such power.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To computer the residue at $z=0$ you only need to find $$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to 0} z\frac{z}{1-\cos z} =& \frac{z^2}{1-\cos z} \\
&= \frac{z^2(1+\cos z)}{(1-\cos z)(1+\cos z)}  \\
&= \frac{z^2(1+\cos z)}{1-\cos^2 z}  \\
&= \frac{z^2(1+\cos z)}{\sin^2 z}  \\
&= 2
\end{align}$$

Comment: but how did you know that $z=0$ is a simple pole ?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani Do you know that $\cos(z) - 1$ is a simple zero at $z=0$? That's all you need to know.

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake, $\cos(z) -1 = \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ is not a simple zero, but $(\cos(z) - 1)/z = \mathcal{O}(z)$ is a simple zero, my bad. forgot that pesky term.

Comment: @james.nixon  hmm yeah I gave it another thought and wasn't right. but how the $\frac{(cos(z)-1)}{z}$ can have simple zero? is not defined at zero. do u mean but defining it zero there ?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani It is defined at zero because it has a removable singularity. Namely $\cos(z) -1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ so that $\frac{\cos(z) -1}{z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n-1}}{2n!}$ which is holomorphic at zero and has a simple zero at zero.

Comment: @james.nixon now it all makes sense. thanks :)